# Ajax request in WP plugin return 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I know it's a commun question and I red nearly all the subject about it, but i can't find an answer who fit my case.

I wrote a plugin to add country and languages related (USA->English|Sapnish for example) I am using Class and constructor for the plugin's functions. It is fully working expect the following function :
I get a select in front with all the country, and on change of this select action another function with ajax, the data passed are ok but the response is always returning 0, connected as admin or not.

Here is my ajax :

```
$('#sel-country-back').change(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).val();
    change_status(post_id);
})

function change_status(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'wmu-display-lang-select',
            post_id: id,
        },
        type: 'post',
        success:function(data){
            $('#lang-back').html(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            $('#lang-back').html('<select name="langBack" id="sel-lang-back"><option value="default" class="no-lang-option">Aucune langue associée</option></select>');
        }
    });
}
```

and my function

```
public function wmu_display_lang_select()
{
    if ($_POST['post_id']) {
        $id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_id']);

        $lang = self::getLang($id);
        if ($lang !== false) {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 200,
                'content' => $lang
            );
        }
        else {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 201,
                'message' => __('Le fichier demandé n\'existe pas', 'cadwork')
            );
        }
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}
```

with the action added to the constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'wmu_add_menu'));
    add_action('wp_ajax_wmu_display_lang_select', 'wmu_display_lang_select');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wmu_display_lang_select', 'wmu_display_lang_select');
}
```

I tried to place the add_action outside the class after the class instantiation

```
$wmu = new WB_MultiLang_URL();
add_action('wp_ajax_wmu_display_lang_select', 'wmu_display_lang_select');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wmu_display_lang_select', 'wmu_display_lang_select');
```

but it doesn't seem to work,

Do you have any ideas why ? I think it's a dumb error or mistake somewhere but I can't find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `action: 'wmu-display-lang-select',` in your JS request to `action: 'wmu_display_lang_select',` and it should work.

Comment: One more thing, change:
`add_action('wp_ajax_wmu_display_lang_select', 'wmu_display_lang_select');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wmu_display_lang_select', 'wmu_display_lang_select');` with `add_action('wp_ajax_wmu_display_lang_select', array($this, 'wmu_display_lang_select'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wmu_display_lang_select', array($this, 'wmu_display_lang_select'));` in the constructor

Comment: Oh yeah, I though about something like that !!! It works! Perfect Thanks a lot :)